# How to Copy only the second latest created file from folder to another folder using bat file

Tags: batch-file

Assume in Folder A, i have two files created on same day as below
File1.txt created on 14-10-2018 at 10:00 AM
File2.txt created on 14-10-2018 at 10:10 AM,

Now i would like to copy only the File2.txt using batch file to Folder B.
Looking for .bat file command which does above process.

Answers are very much appreciated.

Comment: We would also appreciate if you took the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And also created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Use `DIR` to list the files, sorted by create date in descending order. Process that result with `FOR /F`, skipping the first line. Copy the first iterated file, and then break out of the loop with `GOTO` or `EXIT /B`.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\sourcePath"
for /f "skip=1 delims= eol=:" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /tc') do (
  copy "%%F" "c:\destinationPath"
  popd
  exit /b
)
```

If you want to sort by last modified date instead of create date, then use `/TW` instead of `/TC`.

Note that `"EOL=:` is used to prevent the default EOL value of `;` from skipping file names that begin with `;`. File names cannot contain `:`, but they can contain `;`, though it is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Are you missing the `SKIP=1`?

Comment: Oof! You thin?! Thanks, all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Copy" command to copy File2.txt to Folder B, here is it:

```
copy "Path\File2.txt" "Path\FolderB"
```

With that you will copy the "File2.txt" to "Folder B"

Comment: I am pretty sure the user is not going to know the file names.  They need a dynamic way to grab the second newest file in the folder.  Or in this case the oldest file if there is two.